# python/SQL Syntax issues

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I'm having trouble calling this SQL command, I am getting: 'OperationalError: near "'0-0'": syntax error'

My call is as follows:

```
users_db_curs.execute("INSERT INTO `"+table_name+"` (uID, username, password, creator_exp, location) 
VALUES ('"+user_ID+"', '"+username+"', '"+password+"', '"+creator_exp+"', '0-0')")
```

Comment: Syntax depends on specific SQL implementation--you should specify the database you are using.

Comment: @TimMedora I'm a bit confused! :P I'm doing this as a part of a study on databases now that I've completed the w3schools tutorials. That's using sqlite3.cursor() on a .db file.

Comment: Sounds like you are using SQL Lite then. That should be enough info for someone to help you (unfortunately I'm not familiar with the syntax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your statement and it should work fine *if* your different variables are correctly formatted to be directly concatenated in the statement string litteral:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> cu = conn.cursor()
>>> cu.execute('create table foo (uID, username, password, creator_exp, location)')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7fccc2c115e0>
>>> user_ID='a'
>>> username='b'
>>> password='c'
>>> creator_exp='d'
>>> table_name='foo'
>>> cu.execute("INSERT INTO `"+table_name+"` (uID, username, password, creator_exp, location) VALUES ('"+user_ID+"', '"+username+"', '"+password+"', '"+creator_exp+"', '0-0')")
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7fccc2c115e0>
```

[It's probably not the case](http://xkcd.com/327/) when you get that `syntax error`:

```
>>> username="'barf"
>>> cu.execute("INSERT INTO `"+table_name+"` (uID, username, password, creator_exp, location) VALUES ('"+user_ID+"', '"+username+"', '"+password+"', '"+creator_exp+"', '0-0')")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "barf": syntax error
```

So just use [formatted parameters](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) instead.

```
>>> cu.execute("INSERT INTO `"+table_name+"` (uID, username, password, creator_exp, location) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, '0-0')", 
(user_ID, username, password, creator_exp))
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7fccc2c115e0
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
con = sqlite.connect(db_name)
cur = con.cursor()

with con:
   cur.execute("INSERT INTO ? VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
       (table_name, user_ID, username, password, creator_exp))
```

should be working
You should read [Zetcode's tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/)